# Best books for web design & HCI

Tags: website-design, usability, books

What are the best books you suggest me about:

- web design
- HCI for web applications / websites

thanks

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Comment: @Lèse majesté uhm, sorry what does this mean ?

Comment: Check the "community wiki" box when you edit the question. This will make it so that it doesn't generate any reputation, but allow all answers to be community editable. It's customary to make open-ended questions like this community wiki.

Comment: I have changed to community wiki.  Checkout the FAQ here, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq and search for Community Wiki.  Basically community wiki questions give you badges as normal but no Rep.  They are for questions that are more like polls or asking for general suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakob Neilson's [Don't make me think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758) is a good primer; after that it depends on what you want to achieve.

For instance Toby Segaran's [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1286711666&sr=8-1) and Leonard Richardson's [RESTful Web Services](https://www.amazon.co.uk/RESTful-Web-Services-Leonard-Richardson/dp/0596529260/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1286711937&sr=8-1) have helped deliver HCI benefits and "the feel good factor" far more on projects than any usability book I've read so far (be careful not to throw the baby out with the bathwater, they are still useful).

If you've not seen anything on [eye-tracking results](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321498364), its certainly worth a look (many books offer you a free chapter on-line and some reports are available for free).

Afterwards it is worth having:

- reference books of good website design (there are hundreds)
- RSS feeds from prominent designers
- a "snippets" system with common code

Try to use reporting to find the weak chinks in terms of user interactivity (books like [Landing Page Optimisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470174625) help to make design choices more militant), then find approaches to tackle them.

Comment: Don't mean to be jerky, but "Don't Make Me Think" is by Krug... just to eliminate confusion.

Comment: Not Jerky, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74/must-read-user-interface-book) on the UI SE site. Not about the web specifically, but probably pretty relevant. Some good responses there.